# Custom generator for file filter

Tags: python

I'm writing a small wrapper class around `open` that will filter out particular lines from a text file and then split them into name/value pairs before passing them back to the user. Naturally, this process lends itself to being implemented using generators.

#### My "file" class

```
class special_file:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def next(self):
        with open(self.fname, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.strip()
                if line == '':
                    continue
                name,value = line.split()[0:2]
                if '%' in name:
                    continue
                yield name,value
            raise StopIteration()
```

#### Userland code

```
for g in special_file('input.txt'):
    for n,v in g:
        print(n,v)
```

My code, sadly, has two enormous problems: 1) `special_file` returns a generator when it really needs to return a tuple<s>, and 2) the `StopIteration()` exception is never raised so the file is read repeatedly ad infinitum</s>. I have a sneaking suspicion that these two issues are related, but my understanding of generators and iterable sequences is fairly limited. Have I missed something painfully obvious about implementing a generator?

#### Edit:

I fixed my infinite reading problem by moving the first generator outside of the loop and then just looping over it.

```
g = special_file('input.txt')
k = next(g)
for n,v in k:
    print(n,v)
```

However, I would like the user to be able to use it like a normal call to `open`:

```
for n,v in special_file('input.txt'):
    print(n,v)
```

Comment: What about putting that edited part in the `__iter__` method? So you would return `next(self)` instead of just `self`. Also, what do you mean by "`special_file` should return a tuple"? You want `special_file('input.txt')` to be a tuple?

Comment: @Leva7 That fixed it! I feel like an idiot. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've implemented an iterator, in terms of using a generator. Just write the generator directly.

```
def special_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '':
                continue
            name, value, *_ = line.split()
            if '%' in name:
                continue
            yield name, value
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols) for an overview of what it means to be iterable, what an iterator is, and python's protocols for using them.

Comment: Ahh. I got hung up on trying to make `special_file` a type. I principally work in C++, so I suppose that's shining through a bit here.

Comment: + 1 because you went directly to use generator and for avoiding using slicing (more readable in my opinion) but may be you should explain wat is `*_` and it's purpose in the answer (capturing the rest of the values that was returned by split and that we don't need), because it's confusing for people who are not used to or new to python

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

to

```
def __iter__(self):
    return next(self)
```

and it works as expected!

Thanks to @Leva7 for the suggestion.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do but the answer of @Jeff Mercado is the pythonic way. It goes straightforward to defining a generator